# Combining SU(N) multiplets using Young diagrams

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

I am trying to follow the Particle Data Group's [instruction](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-young-diagrams.pdf) (PDF link) to combine SU(N) multiplets. On page 3, they show an example calculation of SU(3)'s $\textbf 8\otimes \textbf 8$.

I understand step (b), i.e. how to add the $a$'s, but then for the next step, why is there no diagram like this,

```
[ ][ ] a a b
[ ]
```

i.e. a $(4,1)$ multiplet of multiplicity $\textbf{35}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting from right to left the number of a’s must always be greater than the number of b’s.